# Unity Facebook Parse Login gets stuck

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-unity-sdk

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Facebook.MiniJSON;
using Parse;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class FacebookLogin : MonoBehaviour 
{
    #region Variables
    // Inspector Assigned.
    public Text _Username;

    // Private.
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _Profile          = null;

    // Store searched friends data.
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    public void Awake()
    {
        FB.Init( SetInit, OnHideUnity );
        ParseClient.Initialize( "IdidPutThis", "AlsoThis" );
    }
    #endregion

    #region Setup
    void SetInit()
    {
        if( FB.IsLoggedIn )
            OnLoggedIn();
    }

    void OnHideUnity( bool shown )
    {
        if( shown )
            Time.timeScale = 1f;
        else
            Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }   
    #endregion

    #region Login
    void OnLoggedIn()
    {
        // Request player info and profile picture.
        FB.API( "/me?fields=id,first_name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, OnLoginCallback );
        LoadPictureAPI( Util.GetPictureURL( "me", 128, 128 ), MyPictureCallback );
    }

    void LoginCallback( FBResult result )
    {
        if( FB.IsLoggedIn )
            OnLoggedIn();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Callbacks
    void OnLoginCallback( FBResult result )
    {
        if( result.Error != null )
        {
            Debug.Log( "Trying again.." );
            FB.API( "/me?fields=id,first_name,invitable_friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,last_name,id,picture.width(128).height(128))", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, OnLoginCallback );
            return;
        }
        else
            StartCoroutine( "ParseLogin" );

        // Get user profile, and invitable friends list.
        _Profile          = Util.DeserializeJSONProfile( result.Text );

        _Username.text = "Name: " + _Profile[ "first_name" ];
    }

    private void appRequestCallback( FBResult result )
    {
        if( result != null )
        {
            var responseObject = Json.Deserialize( result.Text ) as Dictionary<string, object>;
            object obj = 0;

            if( responseObject.TryGetValue( "cancelled", out obj ) )
                Util.Log("Request cancelled");
        }
    }


    void MyPictureCallback( Texture texture )
    {
        if( texture == null )
        {
            // Let's just try again
            LoadPictureAPI( Util.GetPictureURL( "me", 128, 128 ), MyPictureCallback );
            return;
        }

//      GlobalVars._ProfilePic = texture;
    }

    IEnumerator ParseLogin()
    {
        if( FB.IsLoggedIn )
        {
            Debug.Log( "SHIT" );
            var loginTask = ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync( FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now );

            while( !loginTask.IsCompleted )
            {
                Debug.Log( "Testing..." );
                yield return null;
            }

            if( loginTask.IsFaulted || loginTask.IsCanceled )
                Debug.Log( "PARSE ERROR" );
            else
                Debug.Log( "Parse login successful" );
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Click Functions.
    public void Login()
    {
        if( FB.IsInitialized )
            FB.Login( "public_profile,user_friends,email", LoginCallback );
    }
    #endregion

    #region Picture
    delegate void LoadPictureCallback( Texture texture );

    IEnumerator LoadPictureEnumerator( string url, LoadPictureCallback callback )    
    {
        WWW www = new WWW( url );
        yield return www;
        callback( www.texture );
    }

    void LoadPictureAPI( string url, LoadPictureCallback callback )
    {
        FB.API(url,Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,result =>
               {
            if (result.Error != null)
            {
                Util.LogError(result.Error);
                return;
            }

            var imageUrl = Util.DeserializePictureURLString(result.Text);

            StartCoroutine(LoadPictureEnumerator(imageUrl,callback));
        });
    }

    void LoadPictureURL (string url, LoadPictureCallback callback)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadPictureEnumerator(url,callback));

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Facebook logs in, and I display the users name, which works correctly. However it gets struck when logging in Parse, it just keeps logging "Testing..." in the debug log. No errors are shown, it just doesn't proceed.

Using Unity 5.0.1p1, the latest Facebook SDK, and Parse SDK.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try awaiting the call?

Comment: @bit what do you mean? I've sat there for 5 minutes waiting for it to complete. It never does.

Comment: I think what @bit means is putting `await` before your LogInAsync method. i.e your code will become:

`var loginTask = await ParseFacebookUtils.LogInAsync( FB.UserId, FB.AccessToken, DateTime.Now );`

Have you tried that?